# Reclick the first button in the second button(No need to go back to the first button after update just do it with second button)

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have a button that sends the dynamic id (PHP & MySQL DB) from a `<table>` to another `div` on which when the user clicks on it, the data are fetched from `DB` based on the given id from a `<table>`, and then it opens another `<div>` on which the user can view the detailed info of the given id, on this `div` there is another button which is used to update some data once a user clicks on, then it will send the given id and update some columns in the database with Jquery /ajax, the problem is the newly updated columns cannot be fetched until I refresh the page.

```
    $('#table').on('click', '.my_dynamic_id_from_a_button_in_a_table', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

        var id = $(this).attr("id"); 
        $.ajax({
                url:"send_data_to_div.php",
                method:"POST",
                data: id,
                dataType: 'JSON'
        }).done( function(data) {
         //open the detailed info <div> and append fetched data
        });
    });

//After that we have a button on the detailed info div, this button is coming from send_data_to_div.php and it looks as follow in the info div 

    <div id="detailedinfodiv">>
     <button type="button" id="the id came with the json from send_data.php">Update</button>
    //all other details will follow down here
    </div>

//Jquery for the above button

    $('#button').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

        var id = $(this).attr("id"); 
        $.ajax({
                url:"update_the_div.php",
                method:"POST",
                data: id,
                dataType: 'JSON'
        }).done( function(data) {
         //I cantsee new updated data until page is reloaded because the given data was fetched by different event, how can i solve this
        });
    });
```

I cant see the newly updated data until the page is reloaded, And I think this is because the given data was fetched by a different event, how can I solve this?

In other meaning: I wANT TO RECLICK THE BUTTON FOUND IN A TABLE ROW IN THE SECOND BUTTON FOUND IN A NEW GENERATED DATA BY FIRST BUTTON

Comment: If you want to trigger an event on an element via scripting, there's https://api.jquery.com/trigger/

Comment: @CBroe I don't understand how it works, due to the way it was explained in the documentation, my first button was used to send some data to another <div> but in this <div> there is another button used to update some data but the problem comes after updating data successfully, It requires me to go back on the table and re-click again the first button(This is not good for my UX I need to fire the first button generated by php as Json in the second div since the first button carry the id of the data used to request the first info from DB )

Comment: Your description of how this works is too confusing, I can't tell what the actual problem is supposed to be now. What I linked to, explains how you can trigger the event handlers that have already been added to an element - `$('#foo').trigger('click')` will trigger all click handlers the element with ID `foo` has assigned to it. So if your first button triggers loading of the (fresh) content that you want to show - then where exactly is the problem now?

Comment: @CBroe The problem is when the  second button clicked the content is updated but not loading newly updated data in that div, until I refresh page and then click the first button here I can see newly updated data in the previous click

Comment: Yes, _that_ I know by now. But I don't see what problem you have with simply triggering a click on that first button now.